# how to log out, or change user ?? in Team Foundation Server from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

[Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbzP0.png)
how to log out, or change user ?? in Team Foundation Server from Visual Studio ..
[look at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDAI9.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is solution:
erase the TFS credential on our computer

[Credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqyyB.png)